# lost data in bash 'read' with timeout trigger

Tags: bash

I was a little surprised to be losing data.  I guess the exit status warns me that something's up, but is there no way to recover the partial read (if there was one)?  Note below, 'foo' doesn't show up anywhere in the output.  It was written, the read timed out waiting for a full line, and the data disappeared.
I guess I can kinda use the exit status to retry.

```
$ ( exec  6< <(echo -n "foo";
               sleep 2; echo bar);
    read -t 0.5 -u 6 baz;
    echo $?;
    sleep 3;
    read -u 6 baz2;
    echo $?;
    declare -p baz baz2 )
142
0
declare -- baz=""
declare -- baz2="bar"
```

Comment: I get `baz="foo"` on my ArchLinux Bash4.4.23. Strangely http://rextester.com/l/bash_online_compiler shows `baz=""`. So i guess a bug. Also, I find `{ echo -n "foo"; sleep 2; echo bar; } | { read -t 0.5 baz; echo $?; sleep 3; read baz2; echo $?; declare -p baz baz2; }` shorter and more readable ;) What bash version do you have?

Comment: I was able to fix it with `baz=$(timeout 0.1 bash -c 'while read -n1 c; do printf "%s" "$c"; done')` on Bash4.3.46  and Bash4.2.24 . Bash4.4.19 is not affected, it must have been fixes between 4.3.46 and 4.4.19

Comment: Using docker bash images i was able to pinpoint the change to be between bash4.4.7  and bash4.4.11 . tested with `docker run -ti --rm bash:4.4.? bash -c '{ echo -n "foo"; sleep 1; echo bar; } | { read -t 0.9 baz; echo $?; read baz2; echo $?; declare -p baz baz2; }'` so without process substitution so it doesn't affect the result.

Comment: @kamil: in fact, it was [v4.4 patch 10](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.4-patches/bash44-010). Here's a useful fact: the third number in the bash version is the number of the last applied patch, and the patches are found in the [Gnu "ftp" site](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.4-patches). Each patch has a description and it's often faster to just read each description until you find the relevant patch.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bug. I can not reproduce this with bash 5.1.8.

```
$ cat fd-6.bash
  ( exec  6< <(echo -n "foo";
                 sleep 2; echo bar);
      read -t 0.5 -u 6 baz;
      echo $?;
      sleep 3;
      read -u 6 baz2;
      echo $?;
      declare -p baz baz2 )
```

Output does contain foo.

```
$ bash  fd-6.bash 
142
0
declare -- baz="foo"
declare -- baz2="bar"
```

However, bash 4.3 does behave like you describe, so you should upgrade.

```
$ bash-4.3 fd-6.bash 
142
0
declare -- baz=""
declare -- baz2="bar"
```